# Disruption during Gzip - Would it damage the file content?

Tags: gzip, compression, kill-process, gunzip

Please assume, we execute `gzip` or `gunzip` on a relatively large text file (>1GB) or files as such within a directory. During the process, either mistakenly or intentionally the process is killed.

Is there any risk that the original content of the files is damaged? If so, is there an advisable practice for executing `gzip`/`gunzip` differently, e.g. with certain options, or do we need to wait until `gzip`/`gunzip` finalises its execution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

gzip/gunzip should only remove the original file after the operation is complete. To be sure of this, you can pass the `-k` or `--keep` option to prevent the original file from being removed at all during your script or operation.